# c++ default not working in switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Fairly new to programming here. I can't get my default code in the switch statement to work. I want it to display an error and exit as soon as any data input that's not in the range is entered. For some reason, it goes to the next `cout` line after the `switch` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char choice;
const double P=8.00, A=10.50, B=12.50;
double t,w,price;

cout<<"\nPlease enter the state code: ";
cin>>choice;

cout<<"\nPlease enter the Parcel's weight in KG: ";
cin>>w;

switch (choice)
    {
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        t=w*P;
        price=P;

    break;

    case 'A':
    case 'a':
        t=w*A;
        price=A;

    break;

    case 'B':
    case 'b':
        t=w*B;
        price=B;

    break;

    default:
        cout<<"Error. Please Re-enter. Exiting";

    break;

    }

cout<<setw(80)<<setfill('*')<<"*"<<endl;
cout<<"\nState code: "<<choice<<endl;
cout<<"Weight <KG>: "<<w<<endl;
cout<<"Price <RM>: "<<price<<endl;
std::cout<<std::fixed;
std::cout<<std::setprecision(2);
cout<<"Total Price <RM>: "<<t<<endl;
cout<<"\nThank you and Please Come Again"<<endl;
cout<<setw(80)<<setfill('*')<<"*"<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Reduce the number of `case`s by 50% by using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` before the `switch` statement.

Comment: You're a godsent. Just tidied up my program with these. Thank you very much. @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to end the program in your `default` case, you need to call `exit(some_status)`before the `break`.  Otherwise, `break` just causes the `switch` statement to end and you continue right after the `switch` block.

Comment: Since this is in main, one can also `return EXIT_FAILURE` as an alternative to calling `exit`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added <stdlib.h> and used exit(0) and it's working as intended now. Cheers.

Comment: Additionally the break statement in your default case is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to end your program after the error message. You can use either a call to exit() or a return statement.